# How to open a Mongo Atlas backup snapshot locally?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass

I've enabled automatic backups on Mongo Atlas. 
Now I need to view and query a specific snapshot to check some documents? 
How can I do it quickly and safely?

Answer (score 20):

Go to [Mongo Atlas console](https://cloud.mongodb.com/v2/), click on your cluster, then go to Backup tab and download your snapshot:

[image]

You'll get a `.tgz` archive. It opens in a popup, so mind your blocker.

Unpack the archive, then run

```
docker run -it -p 27017:27017 -v /tmp/extracted/snapshot/dir:/data/db  mongo
```

Now you can connect to the snapshot data using a mongo client like [MongoDB Compas](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) using default connection (localhost:27017).

Comment: On windows `//` must be used for the drive and path like ```docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v //c/restore-5f745d065f8089221bb0c572:/data/db --name=mymongo mongo```

Comment: It works for me with the published port `-p 27017:27017` and correct version of mongo image, like `mongo:4.2.15`

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer did not work for me. Alternative approach:

Download the backup from your Atlas console and extract it.

Then run the following in your Terminal:

```
mongod --dbpath ~/Downloads/Cluster0-2020-11-20T15-53-03.006Z
```

Replacing Cluster0... with your extracted folder.

Now you can connect to the snapshot data using a mongo client like MongoDB Compass using default connection (localhost:27017).

You can also define a custom port with --port